# how to detect that user's connection is lost in nodejs websocket(ws)

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket

I have already used

```
ws.on('close',function(){});
```

but in some case even it is not working like if user network is lost, or LAN has been disconnected.
So how can I check if user is connected or not, otherwise I have to delete that user from my user queue but for that I have to again check if he is connected..

Answer (score 0):

Have the user send a `'ping'` message every 5 seconds.  If your server doesn't receive this message for 10 seconds, consider them to have been "abnormally" disconnected.

Of course I made these numbers up, and they are completely arbitrary and up to you.